# spring batch step_execution_id is not in incremental order

Tags: java, spring-batch, increment

I am seeing this problem of step_execution_ids for a job_execution_id not in incremental order .

We are running multiple jobs in parallel and we are expecting step_execution_ids of a job_execution_id not in incremental of one , but we are not expecting it be like this below.

For example

[image]

Is there a way we can make sure that the sequential generator used by spring batch is correctly generating  step_execution_id in increment order ?

Thanks .

Comment: why do you need the sequential order?

Comment: @MichaelPralow We need it for our UI , where we always want to show the latest step of a job.  We are doing max(step_execution_ids ) and for some jobs we are seeing this issue of step_execution_id not in incremental order .

Comment: latest as in last started ? or last finished?

Comment: @MichaelPralow last finished

Comment: what query did you run to get that image?  Take a look at how the tables involved are defined.  (Maybe include the table definitions in the question.)  Make sure the IDs are sequentially generated.  (This depends on the database so you might also mention what DB you're using.)